# Stacked histogram over time via gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to plot a stacked histogram over time. This turned out to be different from the [Using gnuplot for stacked histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819846/using-gnuplot-for-stacked-histograms).

Here's the data:

```
05/11/2014 10:00:00 1   5   1   
05/12/2014 22:00:00 3   5   1
05/13/2014 13:00:00 4   4   1
05/14/2014 09:00:00 3   4   1
05/15/2014 04:00:00 1   2   1
```

The first two columns are separated by spaces and the rest are separated by tabs. The x-axis should be the date and time.

The following gnuplot script is problematic:

```
set title "Test"
set key invert reverse Left outside
set key autotitle columnheader
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.75
set datafile separator '\t'
set xdata time
set timefmt '%M/%D/%Y %H:%M:%S'
set format x '%M/%D %H'
plot 'test.dat' using 2:xtic(1) title 'Col1',  '' using 3 title 'Col2', '' using 4 title 'Col3'
```

The above script will result in an error: Need full using spec for x time data. However, it works if unset xdata.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `set xdata time` part is indeed wrong in your case.

Histograms work a bit different from other plotting styles: The boxes are placed at integer x-values `0`, `1`, `2` etc. and get a custom label, which in your case is the time information contained in the first column. So the x-axis isn't a real time axis.

The following script works fine with 4.6.4:

```
set title "Test"
set key invert reverse Left outside
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.75
set datafile separator '\t'

plot 'test.dat' using 2:xtic(1) title 'Col1',  '' using 3 title 'Col2', '' using 4 title 'Col3'
```

[image]

If you want to change the time format used for the labels, you must parse the time string manually. `xtic(1)` is equivalent to `xtic(strcol(1))`. Instead of using `strcol(1)`, which contains the information in the first column as string, you can process this data with `strptime` and `strftime` in order to change the displayed time information:

```
set title "Test"
set key invert reverse Left outside
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.75
set datafile separator '\t'

plot 'test.dat' using 2:xtic(strftime('%m/%d %Hh', strptime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', strcol(1)))) title 'Col1',\
     '' using 3 title 'Col2', '' using 4 title 'Col3'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping it simple and just using the date and time values inside double quotes. So your data file would be:

```
"05/11/2014 10:00:00" 1   5   1   
"05/12/2014 22:00:00" 3   5   1
"05/13/2014 13:00:00" 4   4   1
"05/14/2014 09:00:00" 3   4   1
"05/15/2014 04:00:00" 1   2   1
```

And your plotting script would be:

```
set title "Test"
set key invert reverse Left outside
#set key autotitle columnheader
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.75
set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by 90  offset character 0, -9, 0
plot 'test.dat' using 2:xtic(1) title 'Col1',  '' using 3 title 'Col2', '' using 4 title 'Col3'
```

And resultant plot would be:

[image]

Comment: What if I just want to show date + hour for the x-axis. For example, use set format x '%M/%D %H'?

Comment: For that you can change your data file accordingly, like:
`"05/12/22:00" 1   5   1` instead of `"05/11/2014 10:00:00" 1   5   1`

Comment: There is no need to change the data file for everything ;) @erictan As I pointed out in my answer: For histograms the behaviour of the x-axis doesn't depend on `set format x`. See my answer for a way to change the xticlabels without changing the data file every time.

Comment: Thats great, general question about Gnuplot @Christoph: Does Gnuplot inherit all C functions? That is, can we possibly use any C function while writing Gnuplot code?

Comment: No, there is a very limited number of string functions available in gnuplot. Have a look at the documentation in the section `Expressions -> Functions`: `gprintf`, `sprintf`, `strlen`, `strstrt`, `substr`, `strftime`, `strptime`.