# Stacked auto-binned histograms in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, binning

There are [ways to have gnuplot bin your data for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471884/histogram-using-gnuplot) which revolve around

```
binwidth=5
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)

plot 'datafile' using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes
```

And there are [ways to plot stacked histograms from pre-binned data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819846/using-gnuplot-for-stacked-histograms), using

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked

plot 'test.dat' using 2:xtic(1) title 'Col1', '' using 3 title 'Col2'
```

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds? I can

```
plot 'a.dat' using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes lc 'red' ,\
     'b.dat' using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq with boxes lc 'blue'
```

but if I `set style fill solid` the first plot is drawn over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the smoothed data to an external file and then plot this temporary file as histogram:

```
binwidth=5
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)

set table 'temp.dat'
plot 'a.dat' using (bin($1,binwidth)):(1.0) smooth freq, \
  'b.dat' using (bin($1,binwidth)) smooth freq
unset table

set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked

plot 'temp.dat' using 2:xtic(1) index 0 title 'a.dat', '' using 2 index 1 title 'b.dat'
```

The two smoothed plots of `a.dat` and `b.dat` are both saved in the file `temp.dat`, delimited by two blank lines. So, they can accessed for plotting using the `index` option.